# How can I fix the yarn error 'Unknown workspace'?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

## Problem

Running `yarn workspace <nohoisted-package> start` gives `error Unknown workspace "twitter-digester-frontend".`

## Details

### Root `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["x-backend"],
    "nohoist": ["x-frontend"]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "backend": "yarn workspace x-backend",
    "frontend": "yarn workspace x-frontend"
  }
}
```

### Command

- `yarn workspace x-frontend start` fails with the error above `...Unknown workspace...`.
- `yarn workspace x-backend start` works, though (i.e., works for *non*-`nohoist`ed packages).

## Question

Why does `yarn workspace` fail with `nohoist`ed packages?

I don't fully understand `nohoist`. I'm mainly using it because Angular CLI in `x-frontend` couldn't read `node_modules` when not using `nohoist`. I'm assuming it only means *don't symlink packages* - that's why I see no reason `yarn workspace <nohoisted-package> <script>` shouldn't work.

Answer (score 13):

The first thing your root `package.json` should contain an array of your workspaces:

```
{
...
 "workspaces": [
    "example",
    "my-pkg-js"
  ]
}
```

The second thing to check is when you run `yarn workspace <workspace> start` the `<workspace>` stands for the `name` in your `package.json` in your package directory. For example:

`yarn workspace package-name start`

The name property in `my-pkg-js/package.json` file should be something like:

```
{
...
 "name": "package-name"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this question is so old and I'll be unable to validate your answer, that's why I can't upvote :(. But sincerely appreciated! :))

Comment: My pleasure ;) Happy coding

Comment: I had the same issue (not using angular) but there was a difference between the folder name `/packages/foo` and the `package.json` `name` - the `name` was `@mycompany/foo`. This answer solved it for me.

Comment: @HossamEl-Deen if my comment above suffices, I think you should mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Solved for me too, I didn't realize that the package.json name needed to match the directory name